# How to make Python continue with a game after while loop or if statement

Tags: if-statement, while-loop

I’m trying to get my game to continue to the games after a user inputs “yes” or “no”. Here is the code:

```
user_name =input ("What is your name? ")
user = user_name
print(f"Welcome {user}!")
user_ans = ''

while True:
  user_ans = input("Are you ready to play ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS? (yes or no?) ")

  if user_ans.lower() == 'yes':
    print("Alright, Let's play!")
    continue
  elif user_ans.lower() == 'no':
    print('Not ready to play? Okay, see ya later!')
    exit()
  else:
    print('Type yes or no')
    
if user_ans.lower() == 'yes':
  def get_choices():  #get_choices is a function  
    player_choice = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ")
    options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    computer_choice = random.choice(options)
    choices = {"player":player_choice, "computer":computer_choice}
    return choices 
  
  def check_win(player, computer ):
    print(f"You chose {player}, computer chose {computer}.")
  
    if player == computer:
      return "It's a tie!"
      #if player chooses "ROCK"
    elif player == "rock":
      if computer == "scissors":
        return "Rock smashes scissors! You win!"
```

The main part I need help with is yes or no part. The loop works except for the fact that it won’t continue to the game after that.

I initially tried using an if/else statement but I’d didn’t work well. I’ve only made progress with the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that way:

```
import random

user_name = input("What is your name? ")
user = user_name
print(f"Welcome {user}!")
user_ans = ''

while True:
  user_ans = input("Are you ready to play ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS? (yes or no?) ")

  if user_ans.lower() == 'yes':
    print("Alright, Let's play!")
    break
  elif user_ans.lower() == 'no':
    print('Not ready to play? Okay, see ya later!')
    exit()
  else:
    print('Type yes or no')

def get_choices():
  player_choice = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ")
  options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
  computer_choice = random.choice(options)
  choices = {"player": player_choice, "computer": computer_choice}
  return choices

def check_win(player, computer):
  print(f"You chose {player}, computer chose {computer}.")

  if player == computer:
    return "It's a tie!"
  elif player == "rock":
    if computer == "scissors":
      return "Rock smashes scissors! You win!"
    else:
      return "Paper covers rock! You lose!"
  elif player == "paper":
    if computer == "rock":
      return "Paper covers rock! You win!"
    else:
      return "Scissors cut paper! You lose!"
  elif player == "scissors":
    if computer == "paper":
      return "Scissors cut paper! You win!"
    else:
      return "Rock smashes scissors! You lose!"
  else:
    return "Invalid input. Please try again."

while True:
  choices = get_choices()
  result = check_win(choices["player"], choices["computer"])
  print(result)

  play_again = input("Do you want to play again? (yes or no) ")
  if play_again.lower() == "no":
    print("Thanks for playing!")
    break
```